# Datatables reset search button - causes jQuery error in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, datatables

I've added a reset search button to a project using datatables and rowgrouping.  It works fine in all browsers except IE7.  In IE7 the reset search button AND the Expand All/Contract All button disappears.

The debugger (IE console) shows this error:

> SCRIPT87: Invalid argument
>
> > jquery.min.js, line 2 character 31006

It seems that calling the function ResetSearchField(); is the offending source.

Can someone give me a hand at solving this problem?  I would really appreciate your help!
I've set up a jsfiddle to illustrate the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/SG8Dm/4/

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
        "sSearch": " Table search:"
    },
    "bPaginate": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 100,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sDom": 'Tlfrtip'
}).rowGrouping({
    bExpandableGrouping: true,
    bExpandSingleGroup: false,
    iExpandGroupOffset: -1,
    asExpandedGroups: [""]
});
ResetSearchField();
$('.expandedOrCollapsedGroup').live('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
        $(this).addClass('expanded').removeClass('collapsed').val('Collapse All').parents('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.collapsed-group').trigger('click');
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded').val('Expand All').parents('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.expanded-group').trigger('click');
    }
});
oTable.live('filter', function() {
    clearTimeout(oTable.data('timeout'));
    var timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        if ($('label:contains(Table search: ) input').val() != '') {
            $('.group-item-expander.collapsed-group').trigger('click');
        }
        else {
            $('.group-item-expander.expanded-group').trigger('click');
        }
    }, 1000);
    oTable.data('timeout', timeoutId);
});
$("#resetsearch").live('click', function(e) {
    oTable.fnFilter('');
    GridRowCount();
});
GridRowCount();
new FixedHeader(oTable);
});

function GridRowCount() {
$('span.rowCount-grid').remove();
$('input.expandedOrCollapsedGroup').remove();

$('.dataTables_wrapper').find('[id|=group-id]').each(function() {
    var rowCount = $(this).nextUntil('[id|=group-id]').length;
    $(this).find('td').append($('<div />', {
        'class': 'rowCount-grid'
    }).prepend($('<b />', {
        'text': "(" + rowCount + ")"
    })));
});

$('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.dataTables_filter').prepend($('<input />', {
    'type': 'button',
    'class': 'expandedOrCollapsedGroup collapsed',
    'value': 'Expand All'
}));
};

function ResetSearchField() {
$('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.dataTables_filter').append($('<input />', {
    'type': 'submit',
    'class': 'ui-icon ui-icon-closethick float-right',
    'id': 'resetsearch',
    'border': 'none'
}));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! After the script call I disabled the function ResetSearchField like this:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ResetSearchField() { }
</script>
<![endif]-->
```